# LINQ lookup if table column contains value and return list of objects

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, linq

I'm passing an object (with properties: 'Key' and 'Value') from frontend to my backend service that has to lookup if given value (obj.value) is contained within a specific column (obj.key) in a specific SQL Server database table and return a list of all matching rows converted to objects.

But the given code doesn't work for all of the cases, for most of them it returns a "Object not set to instance of an object" error.

```
agencies = _unitOfWork.RatingAgencyRepository.GetByType(p => p.GetType().GetProperty(filter.key)
           .GetValue(p, null).ToString().ToLower().Contains(filter.value.ToLower().Trim())).ToList();
```

I've been trying to fix this code written by a colleague for the whole day without any result since I'm not really familiar with LINQ and EF.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's hard to say without knowing more about your RatingAgencyRepository.GetByType method. Either way that's a pretty ugly statement. If you have access to modify your repository class, I would recommend creating a method that simply takes a filter object as a parameter, then uses that to get a list of objects that have that filter property and filter value, then casts or converts them to the object type you want.

The bottom line is you want your code to be readable and maintainable. This line does not come across as very clear or intuitive to me.

Comment: this is the code behind the GetByType method:

    `public IEnumerable<TEntity> GetByType(Func<TEntity, Boolean> where)
        {
            return DbSet.Where(where).ToList<TEntity>();
        }`

Comment: That can't be the same since you are passing in two arguments in your sample code and that definition only takes one.

Comment: I don't have any overload method for that, that's the only one in the GenericRepository class I'm referencing...

Comment: @NetMage There is only one argument.

Comment: I see that now. BTW, you don't need `ToList` twice, do you?

Answer (score 0):

One of the following is null. Perhaps more than one.

1. filter
2. filter.key
3. value of the property in one of the objects represented by name filter.key
4. filter.value

Since your expression is really hard to parse visually, and even harder to debug in case of runtime exceptions my suggestion is to refactor the filter to something more sane.

```
var prop = typeof(RatingAgency).GetProperty(filter.key);
var value = filter.value.Trim().ToLower();
_unitOfWork.RatingAgencyRepository.GetByType(p => prop
           .GetValue(p, null).ToString().ToLower().Contains(value)).ToList()
```